# Does ransomware on Bootcamp Windows affects macOS disk?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, malware

If Windows on bootcamp partition is infected by ransomware, and encrypts all files stored in disk, can it encrypt macOS disk files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because windows can't write to a Mac formatted disk, it can't do anything bad to it. If the ransomware contained an HFS+ or APFS driver for windows, it could in theory also attack the host Mac drive. Of course that won't be a problem, because your Mac drive is all backed up safe and secure with Time Machine. But back to ransomware, does Windows ransomware typically attack/encrypt your external drives too, or just the main boot drive containing the current system?

Comment: Umm I was thinking about just typical ransomware viruses just like encrypting files in C drive and present a popup to user. Question solved! thanks!

Comment: I'm a lifelong Mac user so I don't know much about ransomware. But like I said, Windows can't write to the mac drive. The mac drive is not mounted to the filesystem like a unix system. So there's not much to worry about. That said, running Windows in a virtual machine (like VMWare Fusion) would be an even safer option. Malware on Bootcamp can't write to your Mac files but it can read them and steal info.